# Lenovo Laptop Windows Encryption

Tags: windows, encryption, tpm

Do the Lenovo legion 5 laptops support windows encryption ?

Basic device encryption on windows 10 or 11 requires the following:

- Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2 with support for Modern
  Standby.

  TPM must be enabled.

  Unified Extensible Firmware Interface  (UEFI) firmware style.

The legion 5 does not appear to meet these requirements due to the lack of support for Modern Standby i.e. the laptop can not be put into standby mode due to the lenovo firmware preventing it.

I can not get windows encryption to work. Has anyone been able to get windows encryption on a legion 5 laptop storage drive ?